# Escaping backslash in windows paths passed to unix programs

Tags: bash, cygwin

I am trying to escape backslashes in cygwin, but it seems almost impossible
I have tried a lot of things, but none work right..

```
  echo "C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts" | xargs echo
  echo 'C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts' | xargs echo
```

More specifically I need to get a command to receive input in bash without 
losing the backslash characters.  every time I try to pass an argument, 
the backslashes always disappear, destroying my input.  And I don't know 
how I can tell it to just leave the backslashes on the input alone.

I have tried the following but neither seems work

```
  alias cyg0='cygpath '$*'  '
  alias cyg1='cygpath "$*"  '
  alias cyg2='cygpath "'$*'"'

  alias cyg3='cygpath '$@'  '
  alias cyg4='cygpath "$@"  '
  alias cyg5='cygpath "'$@'"'


  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg0 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  C:UsersTedMusicEnigma

  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg1 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  cygpath: can't convert empty path

  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg2 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  cygpath: can't convert empty path

  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg3 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  C:UsersTedMusicEnigma

  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg4 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  C:UsersTedMusicEnigma

  Ted@Machine01 ~
  $ cyg5 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
  cygpath: can't convert empty path
```

By the way, I want to be able to type C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma without 
quotes. One of those aliases works when using quotes.

Ted

Comment: I had the same issue. I wanted to run "dir /b /s *.txt" to get a set of filenames, then pipe them to xargs for processing, but the backslash output of the Windows dir command didn't play nicely with xargs. In the end I used "find . -name *.txt" instead, which uses front slashes. (I'm using xargs and find from the cygwin package, but in a Windows cmd shell.)

Comment: Set the `x` option to see exactly how _bash_ is munging your strings. Just issue `set -x`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please read the section titled QUOTING in bash(1) (`man bash`).

In your first example,

```
echo "C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts" | xargs echo
```

the shell interprets (and then removes) backslashes within double quotes, so the first `echo` command only sees the string `C:UsersTedDocumentsUnixScripts`.

In your second example,

```
echo 'C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts' | xargs echo
```

the single quotes correctly protect the backslashes, as you can see by running just the first `echo` command, without the `| xargs echo`.

In all of your remaining examples,

```
cyg0 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
cyg1 C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma
...
```

since the argument (`C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma`) is unquoted, once again the shell interprets and removes the backslashes before the command (`cyg0`, `cyg1`, ...) ever sees them.  And...

> I want to be able to type C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma without quotes.

Sorry, it can't be done.  If you don't put the backslashes in single quotes, the shell will interpret each one as a quoting character for the character that follows it, then remove the backslash.

You have a few options:

1. Use single quotes on the command line, to protect the backslashes:

   ```
   cyg4 'C:\Users\Ted\Music\Enigma'
   ```
2. Quote each backslash character separately, by doubling it, e.g.

   ```
   cyg4 C:\\Users\\Ted\\Music\\Enigma
   ```
3. Use forward slashes instead:

   ```
   cyg4 C:/Users/Ted/Music/Enigma
   ```

Option 3 could really be your best solution.  Unfortunately the backslash character is just a very special character for all Unix shells, and this causes a lot of quoting hassles when dealing with DOS/Windows paths.  But what's not widely known is that DOS/Windows is also perfectly happy to use the forward slash (`/`) as its path separator.  Try it.

Note: Of your several cyg* functions, only cyg1 and cyg4 are correct.  The others use incorrect quoting.  cyg1 is only useful with one argument since it joins all of the arguments together into one quoted string, while cyg4 can accept and pass on multiple arguments to cygpath.  However, since cyg4 only passes on its quoted arguments, it doesn't add any value; it's really no different from just e.g.

```
cygpath C:/Users/Ted/Music/Enigma
```

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting, the problem is I really would like to be able just to paste windows paths in the command line as they are. If I wanted to have the slashes instead of backslashes I would have to change them myself somehow. anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes it is useful to give manuals of the used programs a try :-) . From `man xargs`:

```
OPTIONS
   -0, --null
          Input items are terminated by a null character instead  of  by
          whitespace,  and the quotes and backslash are not special (ev-
          ery character is taken literally).  Disables the end  of  file
          string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when
          input items might contain white space, quote marks,  or  back-
          slashes.   The GNU find -print0 option produces input suitable
          for this mode.
```

This option indeed preserves the whole line as is. Try:

```
echo 'C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts' | xargs -0 echo
```

The "-0" does it for you!

Note that for more than one arg you must zero-terminate the arguments, for example by `find ... -print0` or `grep ... --null`.

Comment: Your backslashes will be removed before the string ever gets to xargs.

Comment: @bobbogo Your observation was correct for the original answer, but I think it was just an oversight. The idea to use `-0` is very useful (and I had forgotten that the option preserves *all* special characters), so I took the liberty to fix the mistake you pointed out in order to make the answer more useful as a blueprint.

Comment: i was loosing my mind debugging why i couldn't get `sed` to convert things until this showed me that it was the final `xarg` that was mangling things. its less about reading the manual is more about not treating each part of the command that isn't working with equal suspicion.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when reading a path from windows explorer pasted into command line:

```
echo "Please enter path (copy n paste from Win-Explorer):"
read -r myWinPath;
```

The "read -r xyz" command (with arg. "-r") does not interprete single backslashes in the pasted path.

```
myNewCygwinPath=`cygpath -a $myWinPath`;
echo $myNewCygwinPath;
```

Vittorio

Answer (score 4):

I recognize this answer is quite late to the party...   but I stumbled across this question while having the same trouble myself.

I was using 'xargs' from a Cygwin installation - AND - I was invoking it from a regular `cmd.exe` shell.

For me, I simply used the `tr` utility that is also in the Cygwin folder:

`dir /b /s /a *.txt | tr "\\" "/" | xargs ...`

This completely solved my "slash problem".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when converting filenames like c:\dirname to unix using cygpath I was getting c:dirname, and even weirder stuff.

Turns out, though, that my problem was the filenames I was using were input by users which I was retrieving with the "read" command.  The read, not cygpath, was causing my problems by throwing out the backslash.  "read -r" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts" | xargs -0 echo
echo 'C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts' | xargs -0 echo
```

xargs **-0** option explanation (from [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)):

*"Input file names are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and any quotes and backslash characters are not considered special (every character is taken literally). Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other argument."*

OR

You can also achieve this with [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
echo "C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' | xargs echo
echo 'C:\Users\Ted\Documents\Unix\Scripts' | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' | xargs echo
```

This will replace *all* single `\` with double `\\` before it is passed to xargs where the double `\\` will then be stripped back to single `\`, instead of the original case of single to none.

**sed** is a useful stream editor tool that can be used for simple text replacement.  Here's a [tutorial](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/sed-command-in-unix-examples.html) with some good examples.

Syntax for substitution is as follows:

`s/string_to_replace/replace_with/g`

- The `g` modifier is used to replace *all* occurrences.  Without it, only the first match would be replaced.
- The extra backslashes in `sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'` are used to *escape* each `\` character's special meaning.  So, `\\` would be the literal character `\`, and `\\\\` would be `\\`.

For **no quotes**, you would have to use `\\` instead of `\`, as the marked answer suggests.

```
 echo C:\\Users\\Ted\\Documents\\Unix\\Scripts | xargs echo
```