# Git Bash for Windows showing/expecting file paths with forward-slashes, no drive colon

Tags: windows, git

I installed Git Extensions which automatically downloaded and installed Git for Windows, and when I use Git Bash, it shows the file path as /c/whatever/folder rather than C:\whatever\folder, and if I paste in a path from Windows Explorer, it chokes on it because it's expecting forward-slashes and no colon after the drive letter.

When I installed Git for Windows by itself previously, it showed the slashes/colon properly, but was much more limiting and harder to use (especially with copy/paste).

Why is it showing/expecting file paths with slashes and no colon, and how do I fix it?!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7di3O.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You could also try adding single quotes in the directory path copied from Windows Explorer and pasted in the Terminal prompt (e.g. cd 'D:\Documents\Developer Tools & Docs'). It worked for me. Check out the solution posted in the following link:
[Escaping backslash in windows paths passed to unix programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962485/escaping-backslash-in-windows-paths-passed-to-unix-programs)

Answer (score 2):

It's getting tripped up because the `\` is an escape character in the Unix/Linux world.  If the path you paste is like `c:\\somefolder\\anotherfolder`, it would be ok, because `\\` says "I want a literal `\`.  That said, my git bash understands a single `\` as long as the path does not end with it.  So `cd c:\folder` works, but `cd c:\folder\` does not work.

BTW what error message is it giving you when it chokes, and can you give an example of a pasted path it chokes on.

Comment: Maybe I should have included a screenshot, because what you're describing isn't the problem; the problem is that there's three different git bash interfaces that I've seen in Windows, normal cmd-type, PowerShell type, and now this weird type, and for whatever reason I had this weird type which only works with [forward-]slashes and no drive-colon whereas the others worked Windows-style. I'll attach a screenshot to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the **Git Bash** (Ming) shell, not because of anything `git` itself is doing.

If you run the `mount` command inside this shell, you will find that `/c/` is the folder where your hard drive is mounted. If you want Git Bash to use a different folder name for your hard disk, you can map your disk to a different folder.

By the way, you shouldn't have to care about this when using `git`. Repos typically don't (and typically shouldn't) contain files in the root directory of a volume. Even if they did, `git` references files relative to the repository root. Since any folder that is the root level of a volume will also be the root level of any repo it's in, it will be called `/` in `git`, regardless of how the underlying operating system or shell labels it.

For your convenience, here is the output of `mount` from inside **Git Bash** on my laptop. You should get similar results. You can see that it indicates that `C:\` is mounted on the `/c` folder.

```
chris@caerdydd MINGW64 ~
$ mount
C:/Program Files/Git on / type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin on /bin type ntfs (binary,noacl,auto)
C:/Users/chris/AppData/Local/Temp on /tmp type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,usertemp)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```