# How to make git print paths with back slashes instead of forward slashes in a Windows console

Tags: windows, git

Is it possible to make git print back slashes instead of forward slashes when it prints out paths in a Windows console? I'd like to be able to copy the paths that it outputs and paste it into my future console commands.

Example output:

```
C:\vna>git status
On branch herpderp
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/herpyderp'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Java/HerpDerp/src
    Java/HerpDerp/src/main/java/com/derp/messaging/
    Java/HerpDerp/src/main/java/com/derp/controller/event/
    Java/HerpDerp/src/main/java/com/derp/controller/domain/
    Java/HerpDerp/src/main/java/com/derp/controller/monitor/


nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Instead of

```
Java/HerpDerp/src/main/java/com/derp/messaging/
```

I'd like to see

```
Java\HerpDerp\src\main\java\com\derp\messaging\
```

or even

```
Java\\HerpDerp\\src\\main\\java\\com\\derp\\messaging\\
```

Edit: I should have clarified that this was for working with git in a Windows console. Also, it seems the correct answer for my case is to use Git Bash.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and I don't mean to diminish the legitimacy of your question):  what command-line applications don't accept `/` as a path separator?

Comment: In Git Bash you can pipe through `sed` to do this, but the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) does not seem to have anything that does what you're looking to do.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I was doing this through Windows console. I didn't realize Git Bash existed. I've only ever used git on *nix environments in a terminal. So, I assumed that I had to use the Windows console. Git Bash is fantastic; I don't have to completely abandon *nix tools in the terminal now.

Comment: @LanceClark A lot of the windows command line tools accept `/` as a directory separator also.  But not all; it's really frustrating!  I was just curious which tools you were seeing that didn't work.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, I was trying to use 'del' to delete a file. When the path is 'foo/bar' it complaints about encountering an invalid switch 'bar'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git status will be execute through a git [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) session, so it would not ever use `\` in path (as seen in "[Git Bash for Windows showing/expecting file paths with forward-slashes, no drive colon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29929899/6309)").
See also "[Why Windows Uses Backslashes and Everything Else Uses Forward Slashes](http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/)"

As mentioned, you would have to post-process the output of the command in order to get the correct path format, as in "[Bash converting path names for `sed` so they escape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265269/7490)".

```
st=$(git status)
echo "${st////\\}"
```

or

```
echo "${st////\\\\}"

with:
         //  / /  \\\\}"
          ^  ^ ^  ^
          |  | |  |
          |  | |  replacement, backslash needs to be backslashed
          |  | delimiter
          |  string
      global
    substitution
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's a little old, but you can use environment variable substitution to replace the `/` with `\` or `\\`:

```
C:\> SET FILE=Java/HerpDerp/src
C:\> ECHO %FILE:/=\%
Java\HerpDerp\src

C:\> ECHO %FILE:/=\\%
Java\\HerpDerp\\src

C:\>
```

To take it a step further, you can write a batch file that does it for a command that outputs a bunch of paths:  (`git diff --name-only HEAD~1` in the following example)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (`git diff --name-only HEAD~1`) DO (
  SET FILE=%%i
  ECHO !FILE:/=\!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: It is never too late. +1. Nice use of DOS string substitution there!

Comment: and with PowerShell, it's just one line: `(git diff --name-only HEAD~1) -replace "/", "\"`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Lance Clark and VonC. I've been using Git with Windows, Unix/Linux, and Mac for several years, but I never understood how Git works through the Windows Command Shell. I came across this question because I was having trouble with forward slashes in the DOS command shell (the Windows Command Prompt).

In the DOS command shell, I was calling the delete command ("del") to delete a file using the file path returned by "git status", which of course had forward slashes in it. As a result, the error "Invalid switch" was returned or if I wrapped the path in quotes the error was "The system cannot find the path specified." That is when I did a web search and came across this stack overflow question.

The answer led me to learn about Git Bash and how Git really works in Windows. As a result, I'm switching to using Git Bash with Windows whenever possible rather than the DOS command shell. That is also making life easier going back and forth between Windows, Linux, and Mac. My forward slash and backward slash nightmares are mostly better now and I can sleep at night. :)

Here are some links to concise information about Git Bash that helped me understand how it works:

- [Atlassian: Git Bash](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash)
- [superuser: What is Git Bash for Windows anyway?](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)

Comment: Actually, any `git-xxx` *bash* script (starting with a shebang `#!/bin/bash`) would work directly from a CMD, by typing `git xxx`

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old, but I want to add this for people who find it via Google as I did (I was looking for something else).

@aspoon mentioned that you can change `\` to `/` fairly easily in PowerShell. However, the OP mentioned that their goal was to use the output in subsequent commands. That makes this a bit of an XY question: the OP asked how to get `git` to output Windows-style paths, but then said that their actual goal was this:

> I'd like to be able to copy the paths that it outputs and paste them into my future console commands.

If that's the case, another solution is that if you can use PowerShell as your console, or at least make your "future console commands" be PowerShell commands, then your commands will work.

One of the improvements that PowerShell has over previous Windows shells is that it accepts either folder delimiter as input. Note that in the following `Get-ChildItem` commands, the *input* paths can use either `/` or `\` as folder delimiters.

This is not meant as a *correction* to other answers but merely an *additional* option that I want people to be aware of.

```
PS> dir \Users\Public\Desktop\ -Force

    Directory: C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---            7/3/2022 11:17 PM           2043 CloudBerry Backup.lnk
-a---           7/29/2022  5:04 PM           1422 EditPad Pro 8.lnk
-a---           8/31/2022 11:11 AM            993 Firefox.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  8:56 AM           1070 GET Help Live Chat.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  8:56 AM           1986 GET Help Phone Support.lnk
-a---           9/16/2022  8:38 PM           2260 Google Chrome.lnk
-a---           9/27/2022  4:32 PM           2276 Microsoft Edge.lnk
-a---           7/28/2022 12:47 PM           1363 PowerGREP 5.lnk
-a---            7/1/2022  4:41 PM           1453 RegexBuddy 4.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  1:32 PM            877 TeamViewer.lnk
-a---           6/30/2022  6:30 PM            993 Visual Studio Code.lnk
-a---           9/14/2022  9:20 AM           1917 Zoom.lnk

PS> dir /Users/Public/Desktop/ -Force

    Directory: C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---            7/3/2022 11:17 PM           2043 CloudBerry Backup.lnk
-a---           7/29/2022  5:04 PM           1422 EditPad Pro 8.lnk
-a---           8/31/2022 11:11 AM            993 Firefox.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  8:56 AM           1070 GET Help Live Chat.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  8:56 AM           1986 GET Help Phone Support.lnk
-a---           9/16/2022  8:38 PM           2260 Google Chrome.lnk
-a---           9/27/2022  4:32 PM           2276 Microsoft Edge.lnk
-a---           7/28/2022 12:47 PM           1363 PowerGREP 5.lnk
-a---            7/1/2022  4:41 PM           1453 RegexBuddy 4.lnk
-a---           6/17/2022  1:32 PM            877 TeamViewer.lnk
-a---           6/30/2022  6:30 PM            993 Visual Studio Code.lnk
-a---           9/14/2022  9:20 AM           1917 Zoom.lnk
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I have a nice solution with powershell in between instead:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %G IN ('git status') DO (for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %i in (`powershell "\"%G\" -replace '/', '\'"`) do @echo %i)
```