# Using sed in svn command ignores directory backslashes

Tags: svn, sed, grep, xargs

I want to check status of files in my SVN working copy and then remove them by svn if they were manually deleted (so they can be committed).
i found out that

```
svn status "C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\" | grep "^\!" | sed "s/^\! *//g"
```

correctly finds files i manually deleted, i my case it is jobs\run_tests_on_master. But when i try to remove the directory using:

```
svn status "C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\" | grep "^\!" | sed "s/^\! *//g" | xargs svn rm
```

I get error:

```
svn: E155007: 'C:\ToolsJenkinsjobsrun_tests_on_master' is not a working copy
```

It looks like the directory lacks backslashes. Is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` will test every line of `svn` output to see if it can remove an exclamation mark followed by any spaces from the beginning of that line. If it does so, it will perform `svn rm` on the resulting string.

```
svn status 'C:\Tools\Jenkins' |awk 'sub(/^! */, ""){system("svn rm " $0)}'
```

Comment: When i perform the command i get awk: sub(/^! */, ")
                                                        awk:                 ^ unterminated string (pointing to " in the exprresision

Comment: in a sub expression to be specific

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to improve your command: replace the `grep`+`sed` combination with a single call to `sed` (thanks to `-n` and `p` flags), and use single quotes in `sed`. Using `echo` in place of `svn`, that would be something like this:

```
>>> echo '!C  C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\' | sed -nr 's/!C *//gp'

C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\
```

I realised that the problem is with the `xargs` part of the command. You need to use the `-0` option:

```
>>> echo '!C  C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\' | sed -nr 's/!C *//gp' | xargs -0 echo

C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\
```

This was discussed in [Escaping backslash in windows paths passed to unix programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962485/escaping-backslash-in-windows-paths-passed-to-unix-programs)

Comment: I get an error "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\xargs.exe: echo: No such file or directory"

Comment: I tried to solve the issue by typing "svn status "C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\" | grep "^\!" | sed.exe "s/^\! *//g" | xargs -0 svn --force rm " and i get "svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'C:\Tools\Jenkins\jobs\run_tests_on_master" :(

Comment: @Biba I do not have access to a Windows machine, but still, try to use single quotes `'` instead of double ones `"`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround of the issue, based on the suggested solutions:

1. Store deleted files in txt file

```
svn status "C:\\Tools\\Jenkins\\" | grep "^\!" | sed "s/^\! *//g" >>file.txt
```

2. Remove files indicated in file.txt using svn remove command

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (file.txt) do (svn remove "%%A")
```